# How to sort and avoid duplicates in TreeSet with my comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates, comparator, treeset

I wan to create `TreeSet()` that will sort my elements with my predefined comparator. But the problem is when I give the comparator as a parameter to the constructor of the `TreeSet(MyComparator)`, the TreeSet is not avoiding duplicates. Can I achieve sorting of the elements and avoiding duplicates?

The comparator looks like:

```java
public static Comparator<Participant> byNameAndAge = (L, R) -> {
    //check if they have the same code
    if (L.code.equalsIgnoreCase(R.code))
        return 0;

    int res = L.name.compareToIgnoreCase(R.name);
    if (res == 0)
        res = Integer.compare(L.age, R.age);
    return res;
};
```

Comment: This comparator is inconsistent. You can’t say that object with the same `code` are equal when the `code` has not been considered in the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>This code is almost the same as yours.</sub>

---

#### Comparators chaining

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // custom comparator
    Comparator<Participant> byNameAndAge = Comparator
            // first sorting by name ignoring case
            .comparing(Participant::getName, String::compareToIgnoreCase)
            // second sorting by age
            .thenComparingInt(Participant::getAge);

    // constructor with a comparator as a parameter
    TreeSet<Participant> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(byNameAndAge);
    treeSet.addAll(Set.of( // test data
            new Participant("John", 25),
            new Participant("Junior", 2),
            new Participant("james", 31),
            new Participant("john", 22)));

    // output
    treeSet.forEach(System.out::println);
    //name=james, age=31
    //name=john, age=22
    //name=John, age=25
    //name=Junior, age=2
}
```

```java
static class Participant {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Participant(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name=" + name + ", age=" + age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood a few things. TreeSet does eliminate duplicates, with 'a duplicate' defined as 'any two elements for which your compare method returns 0'. No 2 such elements can both exist in a treeset. I'm sure your code doesn't work if you say so, but the code you pasted isn't the problem, nor is TreeSet's code.

A trivial example:

```
Comparator<String> byLength = (a, b) -> a.length() - b.length();
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(byLength);
set.add("Hello");
set.add("World");
set.add("X");
set.add("VeryLong");
System.out.println(set);

> [X, Hello, VeryLong]
```

Note how 'World' disappeared, because the comparator says it is equal to Hello (they are both 5 length, a.length() - b.length() is returning 0, and 0 is 'equal, thus, eliminate the duplicate' according to treeset). In other words, your code as pasted **would** eliminate duplicates, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Problem is that i want to sort based on the Name and Age but avoid duplicates based on different parametar the code.
Let say there is Object with name B and code "001" that is placed in the treeSet. After that i want to store the Object with name A and code "002", this element its going to be placed on the left side of the B. But now i want to place the Ojbect wtih name G that hase the code "002", this element will be placed on the right side, because there is no other element this will be stored, TreeSet its not going to check that A hase the same code with G.

Comment: Then update your comparator method, possibly using the handy `.thenComparing` method on Comparator which lets you chain two comparators. When the primary comparator cannot differentiate (A/002 and G/002 which have the same code, for example), then and only then the second comparator kicks in which e.g. compares on lexicographical order, thus determining that A/002 comes before G/002.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you for your suggestion and your time.